# Capture Firefox Close Event from Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

My extension opens up a series of additional windows. I want those windows to close when the user closes the main Firefox window. [I know you can detect when a tab closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339551/catching-close-tab-event-in-a-firefox-extension) (and perhaps I should just look for the "final" tab close?) but I want to know when "all tabs" have been closed.

In short, how can I detect when the main Firefox window is closed from an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen the [unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/unload) event.

If you script run on all type of windows, then check the url whether a browser window.

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
    if (event.target.location.href !== 'chrome://browser/content/browser.xul') {
        return;
    }
    // do you stuff...
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, although it doesn't actually listen for a particular event. Instead, we setup an interval to check if the tab container is still available.

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (typeof gBrowser.mTabContainer === 'undefined') {
        // Rest of your code...
    }
}, 500);
```

If there's a cleaner way of doing this, I'd be more than happy to see it.

Comment: Why do you say that? This is the exact solution I used in one of my projects and it worked fine. How are you attempting to use it?